# JavaScript variable undefined on load;

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, var

I can't get following problem.
I define variables like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">var myVar;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myScript.js"></script>
```

myScript.js looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  myVar = new myClass();
  myVar.init();
});
```

if I try to access the variable like this:

```
<div onclick="myVar.activate(x);">some content</div>
```

all is working fine, but if I do

```
<img src="path" onload="myVar.activate(x);"/>
```

I get an error "myVar is not defined". I don't get it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var myVar;</script>
  some DOM Elements
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myScript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">myVar.activate(x);</script>
```

Is not working either?!?!! Weird, isn't it?

**x is generated serverside **

Comment: Thats wrong piece of code , calling on onload myVar.activate(x) , but that function is inside DOM on ready .. not possible

Comment: By the way onload is mostly used like window.onload

Comment: @Liam — It might. It might not. It depends on how quickly the image loads.

Comment: @Liam: That's not necessarily true. The `onload` will fire once the image has loaded which may or may not be before the DOM has finished loading. Either way, it's a horrible way to code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Window.onload vs document.ready ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3698200/window-onload-vs-document-ready)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // this function is executed after the entire document is ready,
    // and it will fire after window.onload
    myVar = new myClass();
    myVar.init();
});
```

Here you are trying to access a method of myVar, but your `.ready()` function hasn't fired yet so `myVar` has not been set to `new myClass()`. It is still an `undefined` variable

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    myVar.activate(x);
    // this script executes *before* the code inside your document ready function,
    // so this is *before* you have set myVar = new myClass();
    var_dump(myVar);
    // above should output 'undefined'
</script>
```

If you really need/want to call this method in an onload attribute, then you should set `myVar` to `new myClass()` in your inline script, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myVar = new myClass();
    myVar.init();
    myVar.activate(x);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint with <script type="text/javascript">myVar.activate(x);</script>

Comment: not yet. I have to find an another way to read serverside generated var x with jQuery

Comment: But that is a different question, right? I mean did this answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

If it's absolutely necessary that your code to assign a value to `myVar` happen in the doc ready, a better way to handle this would be something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    myVar = new myClass();
    myVar.init();

    $("#idOfMyImage").load(function() { myVar.activate(x); });
});
```

What happens here is that you are attaching the `load` handler only after the dom ready event is fired and `myVar` has a value assigned to it. If the image has already loaded by the time the doc ready fires, then this will execute immediately, it it hasn't, it will fire when the image loads. Now you've removed the race condition where you code depended on the order those two events would fire in (your original code might have worked if the server delivering the image was slow enough providing the data - what is probably happening is that the image you are loading is cached by your browser).

As a bonus, you've now got rid of the inline event handler which make a better separation of your HTML from your Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing scary here, you just doesn't declare the variable at a good time. When using online script, variable must be assigned before the browser read the DOM node.

In your code, you assign `myVar` on DOM ready, hence the browser already finished reading the DOM and throw an error.

My question now is why do you need to wait the DOM to be ready before creating an object? There sure have a work around.

Comment: There's no problem is the *declaration* of the variable (`var myVar`). The problem is the time it has a value *assigned* to it.

Answer (score 0):

The following function is executed when your HTML is completely rendered

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  myVar = new myClass();
  myVar.init();
});
```

And the following is rendered as soon as it's downloaded and added in the HTML by the browser:

```
<img src="path" onload="myVar.activate(x);"/>
```

So `myVar` cannot be defined, because when `<img>` is rendered by the page, `ready()` has not been called yet.
Same reason for your second example. `myVar` is null

You should remove:

```
$(document).ready(function() ...
```

And try again.

Comment: I do need $(document).ready(function() in cause of some depencies to external loaded scripts

Comment: So you have to load/display your HTML after these external loaded scripts.

Answer (score 0):

why not simply, depending on what `x` is and where **it's** declared, obviously:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  myVar = new myClass();
  myVar.init();
  myVar.activate(x);
});
```

the nett result should be the same without the error

Comment: x is generated by a serverside function

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Billy Mathews, i do know why it is not working. Thank you very much!

This is now how i did it (not clean, but working!)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/myScript.js"></script>
```

myScript.js looks something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 var ServerGeneratedValue = $('myID').html();

 var myVar = new myClass();
 myVar.init();

 myVar.activate($ServerGeneratedValue);
});
```

Thank you very much to all answers!